# Delete tab based on no color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with some tabs that are a blue color and the rest have no color. ***I am wanting to know if there is a way to create a macro that will delete the tabs with no color.***

The reason I need this is because I have a code that allows be to loop through a folder and bring in new tabs to replace the old each month. When they come in, they do not have color.

I would like to run a macro to delete the colorless tabs before running the code I have currently.

***If there is no way to delete a colorless tab, I would like a code to automatically make the tabs that are being brought in to be a green color, so that the green tabs can be deleted for the next month.-Using a code to delete tabs with the color green***

Below is the code I have as of now.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
 Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With FldrPicker
.Title = "Select A Target Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
 myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
'Set variable equal to opened workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
DoEvents
WorksheetLoop wb
'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
'wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Interior.Color = RGB(51, 98, 174)


'Save and Close Workbook
wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
 DoEvents

'Get next file name
 myFile = Dir
 Loop


ResetSettings:
'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic code to delete Tabs with no color; you must disable alerts.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim Sht As Worksheet

    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        If Sht.Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Then Sht.Delete
    Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```